# Move files based on text content

Tags: regex, perl

I have about 1000 files (they are not .txt, but they do contain text) that I want to move into subdirectories based on a specific part of the content of the files. Each line contains one or more copies of the string

```
DTM+137:20131001
```

where the last eight digits are a date. I want to move a file with the above string to a subfolder named `\01.10.2013\`. Finding the string is easy enough with regex, but I don't have enough experience with any language to make it all work. I tried with Perl, but I didn't get very far.

Comment: Why not just use `grep`? You can get a list of file names with `grep -l 'DTM+137:20131001' *`

Comment: "Each line contains one or more copies of the string"  Will all of those strings in the file have the same date, e.g., 20131001?

Answer (score 1):

If you have a string like

```
$line = "DTM+137:20131001";
```

you can extract the month, day and year from it with a grouped regex like this:

```
($year, $month, $day) = $line =~ /:(\d\d\d\d)(\d\d)(\d\d)$/;
```

Once you have those, you can use them to build a new directory name:

```
$new_folder = sprintf("/some/directory/%02d.%02d.%04d", $day, $month, $year);
```

Create the new directory just in case:

```
mkdir 0755, $new_folder;
```

and use the `rename` call to move the file there:

```
rename $file, "$new_folder/$file";
```

This will probably need some adjustment for your particular problem, but it should help you get started.